# Jade : New warning on multiple attributes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I have updated jade to latest version, and started seeing this message in console

`You should not have jade tags with multiple attributes`

It is mentioned as feature, [here](https://github.com/pugjs/pug/blob/0.33.0/History.md)

```
0.33.0 / 2013-07-12
Hugely more powerful error reporting (especially with compileDebug set explicitly to true)
Add a warning for tags with multiple attributes
```

and I see it in the code.
https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/blob/a38aa552f6f53554ac5605299b6b8c7e07cbdf1f/lib/parser.js#L662

But, what does it really signify. When will I get this warning. For example, when will I get error based on the below code (It works without warning, but to like to know when will I get error so that I can compare with my code)

```
mixin link(href, name)
    a(class=attributes.class, href=href)= name
    a(href=href, attributes)= name

    +link('/foo', 'foo')(class="btn")
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Multiple "attributes" doesn't mean what you probably think it means. It's not an HTML attribute as we know it, but a token of type "attribute".

Example:

```
a(href="#WAT").some-class(title="WAT")
```

Note how I have two attribute sections, each with one attribute.

Better put them in one attribute section:

```
a(href="#WAT", title="WAT").some-class
```

Comment: +1. Indeed, I had code like this in my mixin `div(class=c)(attributes)` , and the warning disappeared, when changed to `div(class=c, attributes)`

Answer (score 0):

*(I found this question through googleing this warning as one of the first results because I wanted to get rid of it ...)*

The accepted answer above did not help me in the following case, but it shows how one can get rid of the warning without loosing the attributes functionality
(it does not provide an answer to *why* it works this way):

```
// using mixins similar to +link(param1,param2) above where 'data' and 'class' 
// below are not named mixin params

// OK (without a warning):
+link("foo", data="true")(class="bar")

// WARNING is shown:
+link("foo")(class="bar")(data="true")

// ERROR on compiling:
+link("foo", class="bar", data="true")
```

*(I'm sorry to create so much misunderstandings as shown in the comments below and hope my last edit here clarifies it to be a valid, although slightly more general, answer/help for those docpad warnings)*

Comment: If you have a new question, please use the [dedicated feature](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) for that. ;)

Comment: I did not want to ask a very similar question when this one already offers a solution that might work. For me it was just a little different. It does not make much sense to create a new question if googleing the warning leads directly here, does it? don't be too picky :-)

Comment: But this is a question, *not* an answer to this question.

Comment: Hang on - what is the purpose of this answer? Is it to provide an alternate method, or to ask about why this works?

Comment: you are wrong! This is an answer with the last example that worked for me and the ones before that did not, but are suggested in the accepted answer!

Comment: My case states that the accepted answer and its examples did not work for me, but I found a working solution without knowing why (but I did not want to know why). Pragmatically I posted it here since it may be of help to somebody with this problem that will likely find it here as I did. It could have been a comment as well, but this way it draws more attention to a solution that may work in a case like mine! If you wanna see two pages dealing with this simple isolated problem and a slight variation of question/answers - fine. I wouldn't like it. Funny to write so much irrelevant content here.

Comment: We can't tell whether or not this is an answer.  When we look at it, it appears to be asking a new question.  I'd recommend editing your post to make it more clear that it isn't, if it isn't.  The "But the solution seems different" makes it look like you are commenting on someone else's answer.

Comment: clarified things in the answer and hope it now reflects a reasonably acceptable answer